# Is there a standard for remote backup file change detection?

Tags: algorithm, remote-backup

I'm going to have a need for an efficient remote change detection algorithm for backup of an ordinary filesystem.

The files are backed up to a remote machine and bandwidth is at a premium, so it's going to be difficult to compare files.  I've looked into Remote Differential Compression and rsync, but I don't know which direction I should go from here.  Which is more bandwidth efficient?  What does commercial backup software do?  Is there a standard algorithm everyone uses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two very good articles on this:

[Remote File Synchronization Single-Round Algorithms](http://www.ijcaonline.org/volume4/number1/pxc3871127.pdf) explains and compares leading methods very helpfully.

[Algorithms for Low-Latency Remote File Synchronization](http://cis.poly.edu/suel/papers/recon.pdf) goes into lots of technical detail on remote file synchronization based on set reconciliation techniques.